# Facebook's explicitly_shared actions don't work on Cordova app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

i'm developing a Cordova mobile app that use the WizCorp's plugin to integrate Facebook for login and sharing. Everything works fine with the Login and the API Graph calls but I can't find a way to make the user share an action with the eplicitly_shared field set on TRUE.

Here's my code:

```
            var object = {
                "fb:explicitly_shared": true,
                "og:url": "http:\/\/samples.ogp.me\/847652538614328",
                "og:title": "Inferno di dante",
                "og:type": "XXXX:challenge",
                "og:image": "http://ecoleft.gr/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/3123143-flame-inferno-13272.jpg",
                "og:description": "Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita mi ritrovai per una selva",
                "fb:app_id": xxxxxxxxxx2010,
                "XXXX:from": "1000",
                "XXXX:challenge_id": "10000"
            }

            var graphPath = 'me/objects/XXXX:challenge?method=post&fb:explicitly_shared=true&object=' + JSON.stringify(object);
            var permissions = ["publish_actions"];

            var publishSuccess = function(data){
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }

            var publishError = function(err){
                alert("Errore: " + err);
            }


            facebookConnectPlugin.api(graphPath, permissions, publishSuccess, publishError);
```

It works perfectly but the problem is that it doesn't ask the user anything and it doesn't post it in the Timeline but only in the Activity Register like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're only creating a user-owned object (the noun), but is not associating it to an action (the verb).

explicitly_shared only applies to the action, so you need to create one of those. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.2